# Attempt to call an undefined function glDetachShader

Tags: pyopengl

In my python code, I have these lines:

```
def __del__(self):
    for shader in self.shaders:
        GL.glDetachShader(self.program, shader)
        GL.glDeleteShader(shader)

    GL.glDeleteProgram(self.program)
```

But when the code executes these lines, I end up seeing this problem:

```
Exception ignored in: <bound method Shader.__del__ of <__main__.Shader object at 0x0000016E4AFFE550>>
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Germano\Dev\Gartic\tests\modernOpenGL2.py", line 214, in __del__
    GL.glDetachShader(self.program, shader)
  File "C:\Users\Germano\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\OpenGL\platform\baseplatform.py", line 407, in __call__
    self.__name__, self.__name__,
OpenGL.error.NullFunctionError: Attempt to call an undefined function glDetachShader, check for bool(glDetachShader) before calling
```

What is going on? How can I fix this problem??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`__del__` is likely only being called **after the OpenGL context is being destroyed**, leading to the `NullFunctionError`. If the Program/Shader class is surviving until the end of the lifetime of the application after the window is destroyed, when the Python interpreter is calling all of your custom delete functions, all `gl*` function calls would basically not be available. You can rely on context destruction to delete all OpenGL-associated objects in this case.

However, it is still a good idea to free up memory when you are no longer using a shader/program object **during** the lifetime of your application, when the context still exists (see [this answer](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/a/47912/78005) for more info)! I personally also ran into a similar issue myself when deleting textures or buffers. I would recommend wrapping your code in a `try/except` block, so it would look like this:

```
def __del__(self):
    try:
        #if the context is alive, you want to try and delete shader/program stuff manually
        #this could be triggered with e.g. `del my_awesome_program_class_object`
        for shader in self.shaders:
            GL.glDetachShader(self.program, shader)
            GL.glDeleteShader(shader)
        GL.glDeleteProgram(self.program)
    except OpenGL.error.NullFunctionError as error:
        pass#do nothing; context already deleted my shader/program stuff!
```

Hope this explanation makes things clearer, as those `NullFunctionErrors` are definitely tricky to understand without knowing **why** they are occurring in the first place!

Comment: hmmm, indeed the OpenGL context was being destroyed before!!! I now placed a `del shader` to control the order the objects are being destroyed. Many thanks, I'm following the tip :)